# Mobile Web Development Frameworks

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, symbian, mobile-website

I am looking to see if anyone is using Mobile Web Development Frameworks, examples of these include:

- Sencha Touch
- jQuery Mobile
- iWebKit

Has anyone used any of these or anything similar? I really want to gauge if the mobile web community on StackOverflow are using Frameworks.

Cheers, 
J

Comment: What are you asking: Are questions being asked and answered on SO? Which of these are SO users using? Which are the best/most popular? something else? - I'm trying to decide if this is "not a real question", "belongs on meta" or should be "community wiki"!

Comment: This is specially targeting what programmers on stack overflow are using.

Comment: The sencha touch forums have about 20,000 posts, it's where you get your questions answered fastest vs. SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the jQuery Mobile stuff in a widget I've done for Nokia, and I preferred to use it over the Nokia alternative ["Guarana"](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Guarana_UI%3a_a_jQuery-Based_UI_Library_for_Nokia_WRT/). I chose to use it because I was familiar with using JQuery and Themeroller, no other reason.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Touch and jQuery Mobile have some questions being answered here.
See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sencha-touch